# Apply CSS if child element is on 2nd line of parent

Tags: html, css

Say I have a container div with two inline elements inside it:

```
<div>
<span>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</span><span>BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB</span>
</div>
```

If given enough space, the two <span> elements would only take up one line. However, if the browser window were resized, the second <span> might be bumped to a new line.

My question is, is there a way (using CSS) to style the second <span> if (and only if) it were bumped to the second line?

Comment: there is not, but  maybe you can trick around it, what is it you want to do, when the second span breaks on a new line

Comment: @meo anything at all, make the text red, change the font size, add a border, etc

Comment: You'll have to see when exactly brakes playing around with developer tools responsivenes in the browser, then using media queries in css you could change element styles.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a trick that allow you change the text color. The idea is to rely on background coloration and you color the second line with a different color:

```css
.box {
   line-height:1.2em;
   background:
    linear-gradient(to bottom,#000 1.2em,red 0);
   -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  color: transparent;
  
  /* To illustrate */
  animation:change 2s linear infinite alternate;
  border:1px solid green;
}

@keyframes change {
  from {
    width:100%;
  }
  to {
    width:40%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<span>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</span> <span>BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB</span>
</div>
```

Here is another trick to apply border or background to only the second line:

```css
.box {
   line-height:1.2em;
   position:relative;
   z-index:0;
  
  /* To illustrate */
  animation:change 2s linear infinite alternate;
}
.box:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  height:calc(1.2em + 4px);
  left:0;
  right:0;
  background:#fff;
  
}

span {
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  padding:2px;
}
span:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-2;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  border:2px solid red;
  background:green;
}



@keyframes change {
  from {
    width:100%;
  }
  to {
    width:40%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<span>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</span> <span>BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB</span>
</div>
```

A *very hacky* idea for the `font-size` where you will need to duplicate the text:

```css
.box {
   line-height:16px;
   position:relative;
   overflow:hidden;
   z-index:0;
  
  /* To illustrate */
  animation:change 2s linear infinite alternate;
}

span {
  padding:2px;
}
span[data-text]:before {
  content:attr(data-text);
}

span[data-text]:after {
  content:attr(data-text);
  position:absolute;
  font-size:23px;
  background:#fff;
  top:17px;
  left:0;
}



@keyframes change {
  from {
    width:100%;
  }
  to {
    width:50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<span>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</span> <span data-text="BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB"></span>
</div>
```